# Quit AJAX loop or find alt to reading in list of html pages to do a compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to get this small script inserted onto all of my website pages.
The script has to contain the token set for that domain.
I have 21 different domains.
Each domain has an HTML page with all the sites under that domain listed on it.
It isn't as easy as wwww.site.com/domain/path, not all the sites are under the same 'domain name' but are considered under that 'domain'.

So my thought was to write a script that upon the page loading, read in the site pathname and compare it to each list until a match is found.
Look at my array of {domain, tokens} and find the correct token for that domain and have a function write the script with the token and insert it into the page.

**The Issue:** AJAX will not quit the loop of searching the list of site URLs after a match has been found so this is all a massive drain on the server. 
I know there have been several stackoverflow questions related to that very problem and I have tried all of the solutions posted. My real question is, how can I not use AJAX to read in and do the compare for the site pathnames?

*Is there a better way to solve this problem?*
*The key to using the 21 different HTML pages with the listed sites for each is, that list is dynamically updated with new site releases and deleted sites which happen frequently enough.

The script I need to be inserted is an analytics tracking code.

Latest Attempt at this (pseudo code because I can not post direct links/information)

```
let tokens = [{ domain: "Example",
                url: "//example.html",
                token: "ExampleToken"
               },
               etc
             ];

let index = 0;

jQuery( document ).ready(function() 
{     
    loopyloop(); //start index at 0             
});

function loopyloop()
{      
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            ajaxToken: index,
            url: tokens[index].url,
            success: function(data) 
            {             
                findToken(data);              
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('fail');
            }
        });                    
 }

function findToken(data)
{      
    //data is a very large string of <html> format, use replace to find a match with the domain
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    data.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        //compare the found URLs to the pathname/URL of the page
        if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf(window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()) >= 0) 
        {
            create_script(tokens[index].token, tokens[index].domain);
            return false;                                   
        }
        else if(index+1 < tokens.length)
        {
            index += 1;
            console.log(index, tokens[index].domain);
            loopyloop(); 
        }              
    });
} 


//this part has been tested and works correctly when called, no need to post this actual code
function create_script(token, domain)
{
  console.log('token found: '+ domain, token);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that you can simplify the problem?

Comment: It already looks to me like `loopyloop` should stop running as soon as the `create_script` path happens inside your `findToken` function. Is that not the case?

Comment: It doesn't, with AJAX is keeps running even after a match is found, it doesn't seem possible break the loop inside ajax response.

Comment: I recommend you console.log a few things, including `index+1 < tokens.length` inside `loopyloop` and see what that value says after you see the `token found:` log

Answer (score 1):

I would try converting it to an async function, so that you can do a proper loop with `await` and break out of it when you're ready

Something potentially resembling this:

```
async function loopyLoop() {
  try {
    while(true) {
      let data = await axios.get(``);
      // some logic to extract token and compare it
      if (somethingsomething) {
        continue;
      } else if (somethingelse) {
        break;
      }
    }    
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('loop errored');
    console.log(e.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't use axios - CORS is disabled and cannot be enabled.

Comment: @hpgodwin I think you're a bit confused, because axios doesn't really do anything differently from jQuery.ajax - they're just different apis using the same stuff under the hood. But in any case, if you can't use axios, you can convert your jQuery.ajax calls into promises.